# How to sign out user automatically from Rails app after a certain period of time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, session-cookies

In my Rails app I have a `sessions_helper` like this:

```
def sign_in(user)
  token = User.generate_token
  if params[:remember_me]
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = token
  else
    cookies[:remember_token] = token
  end
  self.current_user = user
end

def sign_out
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)   
  self.current_user = nil
end
```

Now, for security reasons, it would be nice to automatically sign out a user if s/he has been inactive for, say, 30 minutes.

What is the best way to achieve this in Rails?

I was thinking about using a `prepend_before_filter` in my `ApplicationController` that will extend the lifetime of the user's cookie by another 30 minutes whenever the user does *something* within the application.

But is this approach recommended from a security point-of-view?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Why you do not use one of the provided gems for authentication? For example devise..this gem provides a lot of functionality. It is very good tested and maintained. I would recommend it instead of building a auth system by your own.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to build my own authentication system.

Comment: Why you should reinvent the wheel? :)

Comment: Because it has really taught me a lot about Rails. Thoroughly recommended!

Comment: Okay yes, if you are learning Rails it will help you to understand things better.Otherwise such stuff is always annoying to me :). That´s the reason why I asked you ;).

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar method, but I'm using sessions not cookies. I have an 'authenticate' action in my application controller which is triggered by a before_filter for each controller, this action pokes the 'session[:accesses]' to add 1 which in turn updated the 'updated_at' column in the database. I then have a cron job that removes any sessions from the database that haven't been updated in 20 minutes.